# Google Chrome Omnibar—Prioritize Bookmarks Over Search Suggestions

Tags: google-chrome, omnibox

1. My hands have a tremor that make it difficult for me to use a mouse precisely. [Not impossible, but I'm clumsy enough with the pointer, that I mostly just use the keyboard.]
2. For that reason, when browsing the Web, I use a variety of bookmarklets and/or Chrome extensions that let me conveniently avoid a lot of mouse usage.
3. For example, I have a bookmarklet named "star-me" that will "star" a project on GitHub without my making 2–3 attempts to click that star.  I access it by pressing «Command-L» (to give focus to Chrome's address bar or "Omnibox"), then typing "star-me" then «ENTER».  Well, that's what I *want* to do. Instead, of picking my exactly-matching bookmark name, my Omnibox has five or six rows of search suggestions and *then* my bookmark.  So, my actual procedure is «Command-L», "star-me", «Control-N» 5–6 times, then «ENTER».

My question: is there a way to prioritize matching bookmark names over search suggestions?  I like the search suggestions, but I find it annoying that these *you might have meant
these* approximate/partial matches are listed before the *exactly-matching* bookmark names I type.